# How to set an Entity to only accept specific values with code-first approach?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm currently setting up a database using Entity Framework Code First, and I got the next field:

```
[Required]
public string Month { get; set; }
```

What I want to do, is to only allow certain inputs to be accepted in the field. For example, I want Month to only accept [01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12]. How should I approach this? I couldn't find any DataAnnotation to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement [`IValidatableObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to validate `Month`.

```
public class YourEntity : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public string Month { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(
        ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var months = Enumerable.Range(1, 12).Select(x => x.ToString("00"));
        if (!months.Contains(Month))
        {
            yield return 
                new ValidationResult("Invalid month value.", new[] { "Month" });
        }
    }
}
```

More

- [Entity Framework Validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx)

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot for the example and the article. It is going to be very useful.